# launch-local-near-cluster.sh script launch problem

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol, kurtosis

I'm trying to configure local.test network and I'm getting error with after this ~/launch-local-near-cluster.sh. In attached you will see more details about this error. Link where I'm following instruction https://docs.near.org/develop/testing/kurtosis-localnet

> ```
> ~/launch-local-near-cluster.sh Error: An error occurred running command 'run' --- at
> ```
>
> /home/circleci/project/cli/cli/command_framework/lowlevel/lowlevel_kurtosis_command.go:295
> (LowlevelKurtosisCommand.MustGetCobraCommand.func2) --- Caused by: An
> error occurred calling the run function for command 'run' --- at
> /home/circleci/project/cli/cli/command_framework/highlevel/engine_consuming_kurtosis_command/engine_consuming_kurtosis_command.go:149
> (EngineConsumingKurtosisCommand.getRunFunc.func1) --- Caused by: An
> error occurred getting the enclave context for enclave 'near' --- at
> /home/circleci/project/cli/cli/commands/run/run.go:210 (run) ---
> Caused by: An error occurred while getting context for existing
> enclave with identifier 'near' --- at
> /home/circleci/project/cli/cli/commands/run/run.go:332
> (getOrCreateEnclaveContext) --- Caused by: An error occurred creating
> an enclave context from the returned enclave info --- at
> /home/circleci/project/api/golang/engine/lib/kurtosis_context/kurtosis_context.go:110
> (KurtosisContext.GetEnclaveContext) --- Caused by: Enclave containers
> status was 'EnclaveContainersStatus_STOPPED', but we can't create an
> enclave context from a non-running enclave --- at
> /home/circleci/project/api/golang/engine/lib/kurtosis_context/kurtosis_context.go:331
> (newEnclaveContextFromEnclaveInfo) --- Error: An error occurred
> executing package 'github.com/kurtosis-tech/near-package'

Comment: Can you please edit the question as currently the error message is not readab le due to scrolling

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solve by typing `kurtosis enclave rm near` in command line